# Como ler XML no Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, xmldocument

Eu criei um programa que gera uma `XML` igual está:

```
<Pastas3>
  <Grupos pasta="C:\...\Arquivos\Videos">
    <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 1</Video>
    <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 2</Video>
    <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 3</Video>
    <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 4</Video>
   <Grupos pasta="C:\...\Arquivos\Videos\Videos">
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 1</Video>
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 2</Video>
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 3</Video>
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 4</Video>
      <Grupos pasta="C:\...\Arquivos\Videos\Videos\Video1">
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 1</Video>
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 2</Video>
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 3</Video>
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 4</Video>
      </Grupos>
      <Grupos pasta="C:\...\Arquivos\Videos\Video\Video 2">
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 1</Video>
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 2</Video>
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 3</Video>
      <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 4</Video>
       <Grupos pasta="C:\...\Arquivos\Videos\Video\Video 2\Algo">
         <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 1</Video>
         <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 2</Video>
         <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 3</Video>
         <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 4</Video>
        </Grupos>
      </Grupos>
   </Grupos>
   <Grupos pasta="C:\...\Arquivos\Videos">
         <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 1</Video>
         <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 2</Video>
         <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 3</Video>
         <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 4</Video>
   </Grupos>
  </Grupos>
</Pastas3>
```

O problema é que eu preciso pegar os valores `<Grupos pasta=` e `<Video> ... </Video>` a partir de um determinado grupo e ler todos os `<Grupos pasta=` e `<Video> ... </Video>` subsequentes. Eu já to um tempo procurando na Internet alguma forma de fazer isso e as que achei leem todo o conteúdo. Eu achei algumas outras formas também, mas que não consegui implementar. O melhor código que eu consegui fazer foi esse, mas ele só lê o primeiro grupo passado:

```
 Private Sub ColocarList()
    Dim xd As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
    xd.Load("C:\Users\lourd\source\repos\Teste_Na a\Teste_Na a\xml.xml")

    Dim n As XmlNode = xd.DocumentElement()
    DaCerto(n)
End Sub


Private Sub DaCerto(z As XmlNode)


    Dim gp As New ListViewGroup

    For Each node As XmlNode In z
        If node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("pasta").InnerText <> Nothing Then
            gp = New ListViewGroup(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("pasta").InnerText) With {
                .Name = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("pasta").InnerText
                    }
            ListView1.Groups.Add(gp)

            For i = 0 To node.ChildNodes.Count - 1
                If node.ChildNodes(i).Name = "Video" Then

                    ColocarPastasDestroDoListView(node.ChildNodes(i).InnerText, gp)

                ElseIf node.ChildNodes(i).Name = "Grupo" Then
                    DaCerto(node.ChildNodes(i))
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Então alguém pode me ajudar com como eu faço isso?

Edit:

Quando eu seleciono a a pasta `Filmes` ele cria grupos com o nome das pastas e o conteúdo delas vai para dentro do grupo no `ListView`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quando eu seleciono a pasta `teste` ele seleciona o que tem dentro dela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu gostaria e de criar apenas 1 xml por "nó raiz" do `TreeView`. Por exemplo tem 2 "nó raiz" chamados Filmes no Tree.

Comment: Não me parece que o seu XML esteja bem estruturado...tem `Grupos` dentro de `Grupos`? Não deveria ter um `SubGrupo` dentro de um `Grupo`?

Comment: Nunca usei XML e meio que eu coloquei a carroça na frente dos burros. O xml que eu preciso tem basicamente 2 informações o `Atributo` dos grupos e o valor em `Video`. Então vou precisar criar um nome para cada grupo?

Answer (score 0):

O seu XML deveria ser algo deste género:

```
<Grupos>
    <Grupo pasta="C:\...\Arquivos\Videos">
        <Videos>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 1</Video>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 2</Video>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 3</Video>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 4</Video>
        </Videos>
    </Grupo>
    <Grupo pasta="C:\...\Arquivos\Videos\Videos">
        <Videos>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 1</Video>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 2</Video>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 3</Video>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 4</Video>
        </Videos>
    </Grupo>
    <Grupo pasta="C:\...\Arquivos\Videos\Videos\Video1">
        <Videos>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 1</Video>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 2</Video>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 3</Video>
            <Video>C:\...\Arquivo 4</Video>
        </Videos>
    </Grupo>
    <!-- ... -->
</Grupos>
```

Depois, o código para obter todas as *tags* `Video` poderá ser algo assim:

```
Dim textSegs As IEnumerable(Of String) = _  
    From seg In root...<Video> _  
    Select seg.Value
```

Penso que não valerá a pena obter a informação da *tag* `Grupo` porque a informação do ficheiro de vídeo está em `Video`, mas se quiser basta fazer quase da mesma forma:

```
Dim textSegs As IEnumerable(Of String) = _  
    From seg In doc.SelectNodes("//Grupo") _  
    Select seg.Attributes("pasta").Value
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas eu tinha conseguido fazer um código "funcional" parecido com esse, mas eu tive o seguinte problema: Eu fiz um programa que lista de forma recursiva as pastas e os arquivos nelas, só que se eu escolher a pastas `C:\...\imagem` e depois `C:\...\Arquivos` e então voltar para a pasta `C:\...\imagem` ele vai refazer os "cálculos" sendo que ele já os fez, por isso eu queria usar o xml como um tipo de banco de dados para que ao invés de refazer tudo ele simplesmente salva em um xml e no próximo acesso ele só carregue o xml (aceito sugestões de outros modos de como fazer isso).

Comment: Como eu faço de forma recursiva  ele pegar os arquivos por exemplo da pasta `C:\...\Arquivos` ele vai pegar alguns arquivos dessa pasta, passar para as subpastas e depois voltar na `C:\...\Arquivos`. Por isso eu tentei fazer daquela forma, pôs assim eu precisaria  apenas pegar um grupo e seus subgrupos. E se eu fizesse dessa forma eu teria que criar vários arquivos xml, um para cada grupo. Um xml para pegar tudo o que tem a partir da pasta  `C:\...\Arquivos`, um para pegar a partir de  `C:\...\Arquivos\algo` ...

Comment: Porque não grava no XML apenas a localização dos vídeos? Porque existem os grupos?

Comment: Sim, eu crio grupos com o nome da pasta no listview e coloco os arquivos dentro.

Comment: Desculpa @LucasPedro, mas não percebo porque a estrutura e o código que coloquei na resposta não são suficientes :/

Comment: Desculpe, está meio confusa a minha explicação vou tentar explicar de outra forma. Eu tenho um programa parecido com o File Explorer do windows, com um `TreeView` e um `ListView` e quando eu passo por exemplo o caminho `C:\...\imagem`, o `TreeView` vai mostrar todas as pastas e as subpastas desse caminho, e quando fosse selecionado  por exemplo o caminho `C:\...\imagem` seria criado no `ListView` grupos com o nome das pastas  e subpastas e dentro dos grupos estariam a informações dos arquivos que estão contidos dentro da pasta. Só que dependendo da quantidade de arquivos isso poderia demorar.

Comment: Por isso eu estava tentando usar o xml para "acelerar" o carregamento dos dados. Essa forma que você passou está correta, mas eu teria que fazer um arquivo xml por pasta, um para pegar tudo o que tem na pasta e subpastas `C:\...\imagem` outro para pegar pastas e subpastas a partir de   `C:\...\imagem\algo`, e assim por diante. Ou seja se eu tivesse 50 pastas eu teria que criar 50 xml. Por isso eu queria saber se tem como por exemplo colocar o "grupo"   `C:\...\imagem\algo` dentro do "grupo" `C:\...\imagem` e assim por diante.

Comment: Para que quando eu selecionasse o "grupo" `C:\...\imagem` ele pegasse apenas os grupos e subgrupos que estão dentro do grupo `C:\...\imagem` e nesse mesmo xml quando eu selecionasse a partir do "grupo" `C:\...\imagem\algo` ele pegasse apenas os grupos e subgrupos que estão dentro do grupo `C:\...\imagem\algo`.

Comment: Supostamente só precisaria da tag `<Video>`, e depois ao construir a `ListView` tratava os caminhos para criar os grupos. Pode colocar uma imagem de exemplo na sua questão de como pretende ter a `ListView`?

Comment: Editei, coloquei as imagens.

Comment: O objetivo do XML é dar a informação para construir a `ListView` do lado direito ou a `TreeView` do lado esquerdo?

Comment: Construir  o `ListView`.